# "unexpected T_GLOBAL, expecting T_STRING" error in thrift

Tags: hive, thrift

I'm trying to get a basic test of php reading a Hive table. However, after several attempts at getting it to work I have gotten stuck with the following error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_GLOBAL, expecting
>   T_STRING in
>   /usr/lib/hive/lib/packages/php/hive_metastore/hive_metastore_types.php
>   on line 20

I'm trying to find a way to fix it, with no luck for the past few hours.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: So perhaps show the code for `hive_metastore_type.php` line 20 and any contextual code around that.  The error message is pretty clear that a string is expected on whatever function/method call or whatever is on line 20.

Comment: "with no luck for the past few *hours*" --- it's not too late to choose another career!

Answer (score 1):

"Unexpected T_GLOBAL" means that you have a `global $somevar;` statement outside of the context of a function. This can happen if you are trying to access a file that is intended for `include`ing in another file's function, or by accident if you are trying to make a variable act like a global.

Remove the offending line, and the error should go away - just make sure it doesn't break anything else!

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a syntax error, so it would be really hard for us to help without any code.
If you can post the code for that file including line 20, like Mike indicates, we will do our best :).

Comment: Thanks guys. The problem was that I was using a deprecated version of the program on a modern version of Linux. I just used a newer version to solve the issue.